# Wxpython dynamically changes the content of Choice

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

*The problem is that there are two Choice drop-down boxes in the UI, the content of the second box is initially empty, and when the user selects an option in the first box, the corresponding option appears in the second box。
For example, if the first box is month, the second box is day, and the user selects January, then the second box has 1... . 31, the user chooses February, the second frame is 1... 28。
My code is as follows.*
`

```
import wx

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, None, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer9 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_staticText14 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"select Month", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText14.Wrap( -1 )

        bSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText14, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        # select month
        m_choice1Choices = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
        self.m_choice1 = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_choice1Choices, 0 )
        self.m_choice1.SetSelection( 0 )
        bSizer9.Add( self.m_choice1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.m_staticText15 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"select Day", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText15.Wrap( -1 )

        bSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText15, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )
        
        # select day
        m_choice2Choices = [str(i) for i in range(1,31)]
        self.m_choice2 = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_choice2Choices, 0 )
        self.m_choice2.SetSelection( 0 )
        bSizer9.Add( self.m_choice2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer9 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

app = wx.App()
myFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not really reside in the `wx.Choice` instead it's how do I offer different day options for different months.

The `Choice` issue is simply addressed by changes to the items in its list and that can be done by a `Bind` to the Month choice.
Simply put, if the Month is changed, alter the list of days as appropriate to the month. (The ditty, "30 days hath September, April, June and November. All the rest have 31, excepting February alone")

Below, somewhat untested but you get the idea, I `Bind` the month choice to a callback which resets the list of days for the chosen month.
As a side note, check your `range` command, the `stop` value is where it stops, so `range(1,31)` will give you 1...30

```
import wx
import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

year = datetime.datetime.now().year
month_days = []
for i in range(1,13):
    month_days.append(monthrange(year,i)[1])

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, None, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer9 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_staticText14 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"select Month", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText14.Wrap( -1 )

        bSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText14, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        # select month
        m_choice1Choices = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
        self.m_choice1 = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_choice1Choices, 0 )
        self.m_choice1.SetSelection( 0 )
        bSizer9.Add( self.m_choice1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.m_staticText15 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"select Day", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText15.Wrap( -1 )

        bSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText15, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )
        
        # select day
        #m_choice2Choices = [str(i) for i in range(1,31)]
        mth_idx = self.m_choice1.GetSelection()
        self.m_choice2Choices = [str(i) for i in range(1,month_days[mth_idx]+1)]

        self.m_choice2 = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, self.m_choice2Choices, 0 )
        self.m_choice2.SetSelection( 0 )
        bSizer9.Add( self.m_choice2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        self.m_choice1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.DaysInMonth)

        self.SetSizer( bSizer9 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def DaysInMonth(self, event):
        mth_idx = self.m_choice1.GetSelection()
        self.m_choice2Choices = [str(i) for i in range(1,month_days[mth_idx]+1)]        
        self.m_choice2.SetItems(self.m_choice2Choices)

app = wx.App()
myFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```